# If statements ignoring variables inside click events

Tags: jquery, html, variables, if-statement, jquery-click-event

I'm new to jQuery,

I'm trying to make something very simple. An if statement inside a click event. When I click a button, if the variable is = 1, something happens, if it is equals something else, something else happens. But it seems the click event is ignoring the if statements. It just runs whatever is inside the if statements.

my code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="one">Press</button>
<button type="button" class="two">section 2</button>
<button type="button" class="three">section 3</button>
<div class="textbox">
 <h1>hi</h1>
 <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var y = '.textbox p'
var n = 20

$('.one').click(function() {
  if (n=1) {
    $(y).html("hi hi <br> hi <br><br>");
    $('.textbox h1').html("titulo");
    var a=0
  }
});

$('.two').click(function() {
  if (n=1) {
    $('.textbox p').html("hey <br> hi <br><br>");
    $('.textbox h1').html("sup bro");
    var a=0
  }
  else {
    $('.textbox p').html("variable is not 1");
    $('.textbox h1').html("another");
    var a=0
  }
});
```

Even if I set the variable = 20, the click event runs whatever is inside the if statement. It's like it ignores the variables or the if statements.

So I dont know whats wrong. What's happening?

Comment: `n=1` is assigning, not comparing. just cange to `n==1`

Comment: You're not comparing n, you're assigning n, which returns true when assigning to anything greater than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One equal sign (=) sets the value of a variable. `var foo = "bar";` would set `foo` to store **bar**.

You want to use two equal signs (==), which is a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). `(foo == "bar")` would check to see if `foo` is equal to **bar**.

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much, I could finally finish my slider. I was stuck with this thing. I would invite everyone here a beer, but we are thousands of kilometers away so that's impossible. Thank you so much, have a great day.